# How to redirect to a specific web page after sign out from Entra ID

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc, microsoft-identity-platform, microsoft-identity-web

I've got an ASP.NET Core MVC application that implements `Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI` nuget package for authentication against Microsoft Entra ID (formerly Azure Active Directory). The necessary App Registration has been set up & the sign in process works great. When signing out, the redirect to Entra happens, then returns to my site at `/signout-oidc?state=xxxxx`. There is no such page though, so I want to redirect users to a web page within my application, but I can't get it working.

In my Razor page I have the following for the Logout link:

```cs
<a href='@Url.Action("SignOut", "Account", new { Area = "MicrosoftIdentity" })'>Logout</a>
```

In my `Program.cs` the following sets up Microsoft Identity Web:

```cs
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(builder.Configuration)
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MyApi:Scopes").Get<string[]>())
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Graph"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(
    OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    options => {
        options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout-oidc";
        options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "/home/index";
});
```

After the app has been built, Authentication & Authorization is enabled:

```cs
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

In terms of the Microsoft Entra ID App Registration setup, below are the redirect URIs that have been configured:

[image]

Now, even with setting the `SignedOutRedirectUri` to my site's home page & having the URL in my Web Redirect URIs list, the redirect still ends up on `https://localhost:44363/signout-oidc?state=xxx`, which just shows nothing as I don't have a page like that in my project.

**Some additional things I've tried are:**

*Setting `post_logout_redirect_uri` parameter*

On my logout link, I added the `post_logout_redirect_uri` query string parameter with my home page's path.

```cs
<a href='@Url.Action("SignOut", "Account", new { Area = "MicrosoftIdentity" })?post_logout_redirect_uri=%2Fhome%2Findex'>Logout</a>
```

*Rewriting the URL*

I added the following to `Program.cs` after the app has been built in an attempt to rewrite & redirect to my home page.

```cs
app.UseRewriter(
    new RewriteOptions()
        .AddRewrite("/signout-oidc(.*)", "/home/index", false)
);
```

*Adding a `OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect` event handler*

I implemented an event handler for `OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect` as part of the `OpenIdConnectOptions` configuration to attempt to redirect the response.

```cs
builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(
    OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    options => {
        options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout-oidc";
        options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "/home/index";
        options.Events.OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect = context => {
            context.Response.Redirect(context.Options.SignedOutRedirectUri);
            context.HandleResponse();

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
});
```

None of these additional steps had the desired effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some more digging I found the below changes resulted in a successful redirect to a page of my choosing.

I found that if the `SignedOutCallbackPath` is set to anything other than `/signout-oidc`, then on sign out, the user gets redirected to `/Account/SignOut`. This happens regardless of what `SignedOutRedirectUri` gets set to, since it's hardcoded into the `AccountController` provided as part of the `Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI` nuget package.

This lead to the following `OpenIdConnectOptions` configuration in `Program.cs`

```cs
builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(
    OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    options => {
        options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout-callback-oidc";
        options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "/Account/SignOut";
});
```

Next, I implemented my own `AccountController`, with a route that matches the signout redirect URI `/Account/Signout`. In this controller action, I redirect to the page I want to display:

```cs
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public new IActionResult SignOut()
    {
        base.SignOut();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

Lastly, I updated my App Registration in Entra ID, setting "Front-channel logout URL" to match that of the `SignedOutCallbackPath` property:

[image: Microsoft Entra ID App Registration configuration]

Users are now correctly redirected to the public home page of the site once they've successfully signed out.

A special thanks to Jalpa Panchal, whose response set me on the path of providing a custom implementation for URI that the site is being redirected to.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have already tried all the possible way. Here is one more possible way to redirect user to the logout page:

Create an action method in your HomeController to handle the redirect after signing out.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public IActionResult SignOutRedirect()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Update the SignedOutCallbackPath to point to the newly created action method.

```
builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(
    OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    options =>
    {
        options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/Home/SignOutRedirect";       

    });
```

If you are using endpoint routing, make sure that you have the necessary MapControllerRoute or similar configured in the UseEndpoints middleware.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    
});
```

After this rebuild your application, Clear browser cache and cookie and try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thank you @Jalpa Panchal. While the above didn't work as intended, it set me on a different line of thinking which resulted in a successful solution. See my answer for the full approach I took & the behavior I'd observed.